# Forms DataGridView Events

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView for which I want to create an event handler for double clicks on individual cells. I'm trying to add a Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler to the DataGridView.DoubleClick event, but it will only accept a System.EventHandler. A simple type cast doesn't seem to work:

```
this.song_grid.DoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.cell_doubleclick);
```

Could someone please tell me the best way to get my DataGridView to accept a DataGridViewCellEventHandler? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that you are looking for `song_grid.CellDoubleClick += cell_doubleclick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These events are different and they need different signature of event handlers. You can't add `DataGridViewCellEventHandler` to simple `EventHandler`. What you can do is call some method inside handlers of these events:

```
private void grid_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    DoSomething();
}       

private void grid_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething();
}

private void DoSomething()
{
    // your code here
}
```

I assume you have subscribed both event handlers:

```
grid.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(grid_DoubleClick);
grid.CellDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(grid_CellDoubleClick);
```

Comment: Oh, my mistake was as simple as thinking there was only one type of DoubleClick event. I didn't realize CellDoubleClick existed and I was mixing up the two. Thanks for the help!